# What is the simplest reporting tool with Yammer Metrics in development environment

Tags: reporting, metrics, yammer

We start to integrate yammer metrics in our applications. And i would like to visualize the metrics.

Yammer-metrics have collect process, which could send metrics to Ganglia, or Graphite. But there are a little bit huge to install on my computer.

Do you know some simple reporting tool, with ram storage for example for this usage ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a javascript library that graphs the output of the MetricsServlet: https://github.com/benbertola/metrics-watcher

Comment: That's exactly what i'm searching for, i'm not afraid to say that i love you :)

Comment: Is there any tool which supports Metrics v3?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the Metrics project (i assume is this: http://metrics.codahale.com/) and found that is able to export the metrics to a CSV file, which can be used with many reporting tools including this one: [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/), the reason i recommend this one is because is very ad-hoc and you can design and view a report in less than 10 minutes, mostly by doing drag and drop.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to report periodically on your console you could use:

```
com.yammer.metrics.reporting.ConsoleReporter.enable(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```